# Как объединить несколько версий текста в одну?

Tags: php, git, контроль-версий

Ситуация такая, есть некии текст, и есть пользователи которые его редактируют.
Когда один пользователь редактирует текст, новая версия сохраняется в БД и ждет одобрения.

До того как новая версия текста будет одобрена или отклонена, текст могут редактировать еще другие пользователи.

Вопрос в том как это объеденять в конце?

---

управление версиями, их одобрение нужно реализовать на сайте
на сколько знаю git с БД не работает, может быть есть еще способы

---

отличным примером будет редактирование ответов на StackOverflow
вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/435547/revisions

Comment: то что вы видите, это по сути версия до данной правки (в конкретный момент времени) и после данной правки. Вопросы здесь редактируются и сразу на сайте последняя версия, версии тут видимо для того, чтобы юзеры с более высокими правами могли откатить обратно, если кто-то будет шалить.

Comment: Запрещайте редактирование если есть неподтвержденное или по дате всегда последнее принимайте. Если возникают такие вопросы то мерж самому не надо писать

Comment: @InDevX запрещение редактирования не подходит

Comment: @Jean-Claude ссылка только для примера, на SO реализовано история изменений, и когда есть новая версия ответа на проверке, то текст доступен для редактирования всем желающим, т.е. версий на одобрение может быть несколько

Comment: файл состоит из одной строки, в строке одно слово. один пользователь дописал в конце слова единицу, другой — двойку. представили ситуацию? ну а теперь сами себе попробуйте ответить на ваш вопрос «Как объединить несколько версий текста в одну?» в приложению к описанной ситуации. как придумаете, исправьте соответствующим образом свой вопрос.